# How to get the UserID from other server in Jmeter

Tags: javascript, jmeter, assertion

Let me explain the case that I got stuck for these days.
I was assigned to test the loading time of 2 files in 1 feature named tracking information. This feature is used to track the information (eg: number of user who register to site) from customer site. Basically, there are 2 files (js file and img file) that are used.

Basically, assume that I have 2 sites named: `www.example1.com` and `www.example2.com`.

site2 provides a tracking code snippet to site 1 and requires site 1 to paste this in its source code.

When user registers to site1, this site will request a file named `"tracker.js"` from site2 and request an `"img.gif"` file to site2 with GET method then. The `"img.gif"` file contains tracking information that auto filled in by site1.

Now I use Jmeter to record steps and want to register with other users. However, I got stuck to get the "userid" parameter for the new registered user that auto generated by site1.

Is there a way to get this kind of parameter in Jmeter to run with other user?
I attach some images for easily observing.!

- Register form: http://postimg.org/image/cdnvsxxd5/
- Tracking information: http://postimg.org/image/baf5r43xd/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure if i got you right, are you trying to extract userId but the userID is not returned in response from www.example1.com ?

Comment: @user3360241: Yes. I tried with Regular Expression Extractor but when check in the DB of site1, there is no userID that I extracted. 
For more information, I used the script of the 1st time recording. I change the username/password (because I want to register other user). How I get the userID. The userID must exists in site1's DB.

Comment: If you look through the source of the loaded page, do you see the generated userID in it? Post a snippet of the source containing the user id and the regular expression you are using.

Comment: @RaGe: Sorry for late reply.

- The code snippet that need to be pasted in source code of site1:
<script type="text/javascript">
     try {
             var tracker = new Tracker('MTX-1228');
             tracker.setGoal("{goal_name}");
             tracker.setLinkId("{customer_id }");
             tracker.request();
     } catch (err) { }
</script>

Comment: @RaGe:
- The snippet generated in page source of site1:
<script type="text/javascript">
                loadTracker(function() {
                    try {
                        var tracker = new Tracker("MTX-1228");
                        tracker.setGoal("Registration");
                        tracker.setLinkId("1023884");
                        tracker.request();
                    } catch (err) {
                    }
                 });
            </script>

Comment: @RaGe: Not sure if using regular expression extractor is correct or not?